# Why is the sorting of my array resulting in values being overwritten?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am working through *Beginning C, Fifth Edition* and I'm doing the exercises at the end of Chapter 7, regarding pointers. The exercise I'm working on is the following:

> Exercise 7-2. Write a program that will read an arbitrary number of proverbs from the keyboard and store them in memory that's allocated at runtime. The program should then output the proverbs ordered by their length, starting with the shortest and ending with the longest.

This is my code, which is heavily inspired from an example previously shown in the book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    // Initialize variables
    int max_proverb_size = 100;
    char proverb[max_proverb_size];
    int count = 0;
    int capacity = 5;
    char **proverbs = calloc(capacity, sizeof(char*));
    char **tempPtr = NULL;
    char *tempP = NULL;
    size_t str_len = 0;
    bool sorted = false;
    
    printf("Please enter proverbs from the keyboard, and enter in nothing to stop.\n");
    
    char *ptr = NULL;
    
    // Read proverbs from keyboard
    while (true) {
        ptr = fgets(proverb, max_proverb_size, stdin);
    
        if (!ptr) {
            printf("Error reading proverb.\n");
            free(proverbs);
            proverbs = NULL;
            return 1;
        }
    
        if (*ptr == '\n') break;
    
        if (count == capacity) {
            capacity += 5;
    
            tempPtr = realloc(proverbs, capacity * sizeof(char*));
    
            if (!tempPtr) {
                printf("Error reallocating memory.");
                return 1;
            }
            proverbs = tempPtr;
        }

        str_len = strnlen(proverb, max_proverb_size) + 1;
        if (!(proverbs[count] = malloc(str_len))) return 2;
        strcpy(proverbs[count++], proverb);
    }

    // Sort proverbs by length
    while (!sorted) {
        sorted = true;
        size_t length_string1;
        size_t length_string2;
    
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count - 1; ++i) {
            length_string1 = strnlen(proverbs[i], max_proverb_size);
            length_string2 = strnlen(proverbs[i+1], max_proverb_size);

            if (length_string1 > length_string2) {
                sorted = false;
                tempP = proverbs[i];
                proverbs[i] = proverbs[i+i];
                proverbs[i+1] = tempP;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Your proverbs ordered by their length are:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", proverbs[i]);
    }

    free(proverbs);
    proverbs = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

I believe that there is an issue with how I'm sorting the strings, specifically this part:

```
if (length_string1 > length_string2) {
    sorted = false;
    tempP = proverbs[i];
    proverbs[i] = proverbs[i+i];
    proverbs[i+1] = tempP;
}
```

For example, if I enter in the following input:

```
Please enter proverbs from the keyboard, and enter in nothing to stop.
Hello World
Bye
This is the longest string
```

Then I get this output:

```
Your proverbs ordered by their length are:
Hello World

Hello World

This is the longest string
```

It appears that when my code finds that "Bye" and "Hello World" need to be switched, it actually overwrites "Bye" with "Hello World".

I ran my code with `gdb` and tried to step through the code when it's switching those two strings, but I was not able to find out why it's behaving that way. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are worried about the sorting, perhaps you could use the standard C function [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort)?

Comment: `proverbs[i] = proverbs[i+i];` That's not a 1 in there, that's i+i.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @dratenik that solved the issue, I can't believe I missed that! I spent way too much time trying to figure this out. Thanks a lot. Also, I'll try out qsort and will change that for loop to be `i < count - 2`.

Comment: Note: I found it with syntax highlighting "wait, that one looks weird", you can see it in the way SO has highlighted the code as well.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `i < count -1` works correctly instead of `i < count - 2`. can you explain why said that.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError output with `i < count - 1` -> https://ideone.com/IMSvz7, output with `i < count - 2` -> https://ideone.com/sshgJS. I have removed `\n` from printf for removing extra line from output.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: The goal of the exercise is not to sort data. The goal is to learn to program in C. Suggesting using `qsort` is like telling a person lifting weights at a gym to use a forklift. It will not exercise their muscles.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Nice analogy. :-) I didn't get the impression that implementing a sorting algorithm from scratch was one of the main goals and learning about the tools available in the toolbox is also important.

Answer (score 0):

As dratenik pointed out in the comments, I mistakenly wrote `proverbs[i] = proverbs[i+i]` instead of `proverbs[i] = proverbs[i+1]`. Changing that line fixed the issue.